# Is it possible to find $x^2$ in terms of $a$ in $x^4 \cosh (\pi x)-\left(x^2-1\right)^4 \sinh (3 x+a)-x^2=0$?

Tags: trigonometry, problem-solving, fundamental-solution

I have this equation:
$$x^4 \cosh (\pi  x)-\left(x^2-1\right)^4 \sinh (3 x+a)-x^2=0$$
where $0<a<\infty$ and $0<x<\infty$. Is it possible to apply some change of variable or something to find $x^2$ in terms of $a$?

Comment: Mathematica can't do it, so it almost certainly doesn't suffice to use even slightly obscure functions like [Lambert W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), and is likely to be highly difficult if a solution can be written down with named functions at all.

Answer (score 3):

There is no possible closed form solution but we can do a few things

Consider the implicit equation$$x^4 \cosh (\pi  x)-\left(x^2-1\right)^4 \sinh (3 x+a)-x^2=0\tag 1$$
Fist, let $x^2=t$ to get
$$t^2 \cosh \left(\pi\sqrt{t}\right)-(t-1)^4 \sinh \left(3 \sqrt{t}+a\right)-t=0\tag 2$$
From $(2)$, we have
$$a=\sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{t \left(t \cosh \left(\pi 
   \sqrt{t}\right)-1\right)}{(t-1)^4}\right)-3 \sqrt{t}\tag 3$$ which gives the relation between $a$ and $x^2$.

The problem is that $a$ can be positive only if $0.440506 \leq t \leq 2.76039$ and, in this domain, $a$ varies between $0$ and $\infty$. Because of the vertical asymptote, for a given value of $a$, there are two solutions in $t$.

I give you below a table
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
  t & a \\
 0.45 & 0.15708 \\
 0.50 & 0.94034 \\
 0.55 & 1.68159 \\
 0.60 & 2.41815 \\
 0.65 & 3.17995 \\
 0.70 & 3.99655 \\
 0.75 & 4.90465 \\
 0.80 & 5.95923 \\
 0.85 & 7.25830 \\
 0.90 & 9.01713 \\
 0.95 & 11.9171 \\
 1.00 & \infty \\
 1.05 & 12.1481 \\
 1.10 & 9.48116 \\
 1.15 & 7.95937 \\
 1.20 & 6.90374 \\
 1.25 & 6.10181 \\
 1.30 & 5.45912 \\
 1.35 & 4.92546 \\
 1.40 & 4.47092 \\
 1.45 & 4.07630 \\
 1.50 & 3.72855 \\
 1.55 & 3.41839 \\
 1.60 & 3.13899 \\
 1.65 & 2.88522 \\
 1.70 & 2.65309 \\
 1.75 & 2.43945 \\
 1.80 & 2.24179 \\
 1.85 & 2.05805 \\
 1.90 & 1.88655 \\
 1.95 & 1.72588 \\
 2.00 & 1.57485 \\
 2.05 & 1.43247 \\
 2.10 & 1.29786 \\
 2.15 & 1.17029 \\
 2.20 & 1.04911 \\
 2.25 & 0.93376 \\
 2.30 & 0.82375 \\
 2.35 & 0.71864 \\
 2.40 & 0.61805 \\
 2.45 & 0.52164 \\
 2.50 & 0.42909 \\
 2.55 & 0.34014 \\
 2.60 & 0.25453 \\
 2.65 & 0.17204 \\
 2.70 & 0.09247 \\
 2.75 & 0.01564
\end{array}
\right)$$ So, for a given value of $a$, you can pick an estimate of $t$ and safely use Newton method.

Let us try for $a=5$; the iterates will be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & t_n \\
 0 & 0.75000000 \\
 1 & 0.75480447 \\
 2 & 0.75488029 \\
 3 & 0.75488031
\end{array}
\right)$$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & t_n \\
 0 & 1.35000000 \\
 1 & 1.34282664 \\
 2 & 1.34248914 \\
 3 & 1.34248842
\end{array}
\right)$$